# Unsupported operand type error coming in while loop

Tags: error-handling

I am using two major while loops. One for taking input. Other for running tests.

I got this error:

```
Error : File "n1.py", line 22, in <module>    while j<n-1 and line[a][j+1]-line[a][j]<=2: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'
```

Why am I getting error when everything is integer type in this line.

[image: I have attached the screenshot of my editor.]

Comment: Please don't use screenshot to share your code, instead copy it directly in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is not integer. On **line 3** you have `n=[]` (this is a **list**) and then on **line 21** you do `n-1`

You can't use a **substraction** between an **int** and a **list**.

This results in:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'
```

---

Maybe you want to access the **last item** in the list

```py
n[-1] # Make sure there is at least one item otherwise it throws an IndexError
```

Or maybe you want to get the **last index** of the list

```py
len(n) - 1
```